# How do I traverse three tables and get the maximum of a value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-4.1

In my EntityFramework I have three associated tables like so:

[image: In my EntityFramework I have three associated tables like so:]

I'm trying to get the last time a file was used on a job. I have a value for File.Name and I need to get the maximum value for Job.ExecutedOn. I can obtain the File.FileId with a where clause, then in a separate expression get a list of FileHistory.JobId, then finally in a third expression get the maximum of Job.ExecutedOn. It feels very clumsy.

I was hoping for a single expression that accepts a value for File.Name and traverses across the tables to return the maximum value for Job.ExecutedOn. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
 DateTime GetLastExecutionTime(ObjectContext context, string fileName)
 {
    var query = from file in context.Files
                    join history in context.FileHistories 
                        on file.FileID equals history.FileID
                    join job in context.Jobs 
                        on history.JobID equals job.JobID
                    where file.FileName == fileName
                    select job.ExecutedOn;

    var result = query.Max();
 }
```

Comment: There where a few errors in your query syntax, I updated the answer to correct them.

Comment: jeroenh, nice touch to put it in a function. Thanks

Comment: Scott, thanks for your help. I should have thought about joins.

Comment: Scott, thank you for correcting me - that always happens to me when not slapped by the compiler :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work for you:

```
var query =
    from file in dc.Files
    where file.Name == fileName
    from history in file.FileHistories
    orderby history.Job.ExecutedOn descending
    select history.Job.ExecutedOn;
var lastExecutedDate = query.First();
```

I wrote it in a way so you could easily return the associated job instead.  To do that just change the final projection to `select history.Job`.

Otherwise you could just remove the sort and take the `Max()` of the query (instead of `First()`).

Comment: Jeff, super fingers, nice touch to juggle the joins to access the Job. It turns out I will need to do that in another application. Thanks